# How do we dismiss actionbar SearchView?

Tags: android

I want to dismiss my actionbar searchview after the user submits a search. This is what I have:

```
SearchView.OnQueryTextListener listener = new OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        mSearchView.setIconified(true);
        return false;
    }
};
```

but it appears to have no effect. I've also tried keeping a reference to its menu item and doing:

```
mSearchMenuItem.collapseActionView();
```

no effect. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Does your `onQueryTextSubmit` method get called?

Comment: Yes, everything is working apart from that.

Answer (score 1):

You could set its visibility in order to make it invisible :

```
mSearchView.setVisible(false);
```

Then turn it back to `true` when you come back on the activity

**EDIT**

In my case, but `mSearchMenuItem.collapseActionView();` worked, but I had to add `mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(null);` just before it. Maybe you can try that too.